# c: valgrind "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm getting an error in valgrind and don't know what is wrong.
The error is:
valgrind output:

> ```
> ==1112== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ==1112==    at 0x402BF0D: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
> ```

And it states the problem occurs on line 226:

```
if(reallocate ==TRUE)
{
    char** temp_values = NULL;


    temp_values = (char**) realloc(theBoard->_values, theBoard->_size_r*sizeof(char*) );

    if(temp_values!=NULL)
    {
        theBoard->_values = temp_values;
    } else
    {
        reportError(MEM_OUT);
        return FALSE;
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<theBoard->_size_r; i++)
    {
        char* temp_values_c = NULL;
HERE( line 226)->   temp_values_c = realloc(theBoard->_values[i], theBoard->_size_c*sizeof(char) );

        if(temp_values_c != NULL)
        {
            theBoard->_values[i] = temp_values_c;
        } else
        {
            reportError(MEM_OUT);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // initialize extra memory
    if(row_out_bound)
    {
        init(theBoard,prev_size_r,0);
    }

    if(col_out_bound)
    {
        init(theBoard,0, prev_size_c);
    }

}
```

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: If you run valgrind with --track-origins=yes, it'll tell you the conflicting variable and where it was allocated.

Comment: Was there a Valgrind update this week? This is the 3rd or so question about the very same problem I encountered within the last few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `theBoard->_values[i]` is not initialized since it comes straight from `realloc` (`temp_values = ...`).

#### EDIT

> Can you elaborate please?

I thought you'd never ask. The function `realloc` returns a chunk of memory of the specified size, **with no guarantees regarding its contents**. So for all practical purposes you should assume anything `realloc` returns contains garbage. In your code you take that (potential) garbage and on line `226` you tell realloc:

*Here's this pointer that's like totally valid and all. It's `NULL` or I previously obtained it from `malloc`. Can you realloc it to this size?* And that's not true! The actual value contained by `theBoard->_values[i]` could be anything.

What you want is a loop that does `theBoard->_values[i] = NULL`, or maybe use `malloc` instead of `realloc` on line 226.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How can i fix this?

Comment: i can't use malloc because i have previous values in there i want to keep. I can't stand the first option you suggested - what to do in the loop?

Comment: @Tom Well, in this case the `realloc` is useless, since theBoard->_values[i] is garbage. In the loop you could say `theBoard->_values[i] = NULL`

Comment: @Tom Did that fix it for you ?